# Long lasting structures: a comparison

Tags: concrete, construction, stone

How long does each composite hold given that the structures are built in the northern hemisphere e.g scandinavia. If not known, perhaps a prediction could be made.

**Rebar cage + concrete: 100 years.**

**Rebar cage + stone* + poured concrete: ?**

**Stone* + poured concrete: ?**

**Stone* + mortar: ?**

**Rebar cage + stone* + mortar: ?**

*stone = Granite, quartzite or sandstone

**Motivation**

Imagine I want to build a structure/house that will last for a thousand years, or close to it. Why? Because given the effort and the amount of money spent on the building I want it to last, even if I sell it.

Comment: I will suggest that the life of any of those building techniques will be influenced more by other things than by the specific building technique chosen.  For example, the foundation, the roof, the slope of land adjacent to the building, and the maintenance the building receives over its lifetime.

Comment: Yes, but not if the variables are the same. Assume the exact same values of the variables and only look at the building techniques themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top three things that decide a building's longevity are:

- The roof
- The roof
- The roof

So, if you are serious about this, there are two ways to go.

### Invent a 1000 year roof

Good luck.   Nobody has figured out that one.   Well, cavers have.

### Make a structure that will last 900 years after the roof fails.

This is the fun one!  Heck, it's be worthy of a doctorate thesis.

When the roof fails, make the rest of the structure stable enough that the next guy can just put another roof on it.

Fortunately you're in Europe, where there are thousands of ruins to study, so you have lots of examples of what has worked in the past.   You can blend this with the latest fabrication tech.

By the way, concrete does not have a 100 year life.  There is 2000 year old concrete out there.  The biggest problem in concrete is the use of steel reinforcing rod, which oxidizes when exposed to water and expands when it oxidizes.  This causes a "jacking effect" which greatly worsens water leakage and ultimately shatters the concrete structure.  There are other re-rod materials which do not do that, they are not used because they are more expensive.

Comment: How can steel reinforcing rods (rebar) be exposed to water if its surrounded by concrete? And if water slips through, why do constructions have rebar to begin with? It makes sense that the roof has a big part of the longevity. Does that mean that taller buildings are not as lasting, provided they have the same roof? I think the roof can more easily be renovated than the wall-structures, that's why Im more interested in those.

Comment: Rebar gives the concrete tensile strength.  They use steel because it's cheap and they're content to build a 70 year structure.   You're not.   If you assume your succesors will faithfully maintain the roof, then your question is answered by any older building in Europe, and you don't need to ask us lol!

Comment: So let me get this straight.. regardless of how I built it, if I change or renovate the roof then the building will last? So the reason why wood houses don't last very long is because the roof (mainly) and if they did change the roof every 30 years it would last for a long time?

Comment: Correct.  And to see that in action, visit the USA rustbelt or the former Societ bloc.   The building does alright -until- the roof starts to leak.  Then water ingress starts attacking the structure itself.  Catch it fast you can save the building, but eventually (5-30 years) the structure fails.  Usually.  Some structures, the walls will long outlive the roof collapsing and decaying into dirt. Again Europe is full of examples.